# Nuxtjs auth not working, I am using Laravel sanctum on front end back both

Tags: laravel, authentication, nuxt.js, single-page-application, laravel-sanctum

I am building a web application, on the front end side I am using Nuxt js (Laravel sanctum package) and on the back end side I am using Laravel sanctum

I configure the front-end and back-end both, cookies are also generating correctly but I unable to hit the Laravel route. When I send the request it return 200 code with the cookie but Laravel method return nothing, it's means that my app is not hitting the Laravel method. After clicking on the login button I am redirected to the dashboard but console return no response with no error.

My login page headers

```
Request URL: http://localhost:3000/http://localhost:8000/api/admin/login
Request Method: POST
Status Code: 200 OK
Remote Address: 127.0.0.1:3000
Referrer Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin
Accept-Ranges: none
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 2779
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Date: Mon, 24 May 2021 16:08:05 GMT
ETag: "adb-BuJ98IeCR24JYV5bINxcPHcMBsc"
Accept: application/json
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9,la;q=0.8,mt;q=0.7,id;q=0.6,pl;q=0.5,fr;q=0.4
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 2
Content-Type: application/json
Cookie: auth.strategy=laravelSanctum; auth._token_expiration.laravelSanctum=false; auth._token.laravelSanctum=false
Host: localhost:3000
Origin: http://localhost:3000
Referer: http://localhost:3000/admin/login
sec-ch-ua: " Not A;Brand";v="99", "Chromium";v="90", "Google Chrome";v="90"
sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0
Sec-Fetch-Dest: empty
Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors
Sec-Fetch-Site: same-origin
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/90.0.4430.212 Safari/537.36
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
```

Api.php

```
Route::prefix('admin')->group(function(){
    Route::post('/login', [LoginController::class, 'login'])->name('admin.login');
});
```

LoginController.php

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Admin;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class LoginController extends Controller
{
    public function login(Request $request)
    {
        return "Login Success";// Just for testing
    }
}
```

nuxt.config.js

```
modules: [
    'bootstrap-vue/nuxt',
    '@nuxtjs/axios',
    '@nuxtjs/auth-next'
  ],

auth: {
    strategies: {
      'laravelSanctum': {
        provider: 'laravel/sanctum',
        url: '/http://localhost:8000',
        endpoints:{
          login:{
            url:'/api/admin/login',
            withCredentials: true,
            method: 'post',
          },
          logout:{
            url:'admin/logout'
          },
          user:{
            url:'/user'
          },
        },
        user:{
          property:Array
        }
      },
    },
    redirect:{
      login: '/admin/login',
      logout: '/',
      home: '/'

    }
  },
```

Login.vue

```
<template>
<div>
  <index />
  <b-container>

    <b-row>
      <b-col cols="*" sm="*" md="6" lg="6" class="mx-auto mt-5 offset-2">
        <b-card title="Login Page">
          <b-form>

            <b-form-group>
              <label for="text-email">Email</label>
              <b-form-input type="email" v-model="form.email" aria-describedby="email-help-block"></b-form-input>
            </b-form-group>
            <b-form-group>
              <label for="text-password">Password</label>
              <b-form-input type="password" v-model="form.password" aria-describedby="password-help-block"></b-form-input>
            </b-form-group>
            <b-form-group>
              <b-button type="submit" @click.prevent="login()" block variant="primary">Login</b-button>
            </b-form-group>
          </b-form>
        </b-card>
      </b-col>
    </b-row>
  </b-container>
</div>
</template>

<script>
import index from '../index.vue'
export default {
  components: { index },
  data(){
    return {
      form:{
        email: '',
        password: '',
      }
    }
  },
  methods:{
    async login(){
      await this.$auth.loginWith('laravelSanctum', {
        data: {
          email: this.email,
          password: this.password
        }
      })
      .then( (response) => {
        this.$router.push('/admin/dashboard')
        console.log( response );
      })
      .catch( (error) => {
        console.log( error );
      })
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

package.json

```
 "dependencies": {
    "@nuxtjs/auth-next": "5.0.0-1620773067.c356fed",
    "bootstrap": "^4.6.0",
    "bootstrap-vue": "^2.21.2",
    "core-js": "^3.9.1",
    "nuxt": "^2.15.3"
  },
```

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with this request URL: `Request URL: http://localhost:3000/http://localhost:8000/api/admin/login`?

Comment: @JohnHanley this base URL is automatically added by Nuxtjs, If I remove this localhot:3000, my app will not work, how can I get rid of them.

Comment: @JohnHanley my client App is running on port localhost:3000 and my laravel API is running on localhost:8000. If I remove the subdomain localhost:3000 it did not work.

Answer (score 1):

remove starting "/" from auth.strategies.laravelSanctum.url in nuxt.config.js
file

```
url: '/http://localhost:8000',
```

to

```
url: 'http://localhost:8000',
```

Answer (score 0):

My request URL is invalid, the spa domain added in the URL that's why my spa is not sending requests to the server.

```
Request URL: http://localhost:3000/http://localhost:8000/api/admin/login
```

TO

```
Request URL: http://localhost:8000/api/admin/login
```

That works fine.